# jinja2: check if dict contains ANY item from list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to do something like the following (I realize this isn't valid).

Vars from Ansible:

```
---
items:
  - min_cpu
  - min_mem
  - max_cpu
  - max_mem
```

Templated file (not valid):

```
{% if any(items in container) %}
```

I can of course type it up manually:

```
{% if 'min_cpu' in container or 'min_mem' in container ...
```

But, I would like to not duplicate the data, and not have to specify it all manually.

Comment: is `if items | intersect(container.keys())` what you're looking for? ([intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) is provided by ansible, not by jinja)

Comment: Ah, yes.  Use set set theory functions might do the trick.